# Compile and link .h header files which many .c source programs use

Tags: c, gcc, hyperlink, header, compilation

I work for a group in which our test bucket has hundreds of .c source programs.  The .c programs are fairly small and they all include the same 10 .h header files.  These .h files are fairly large.

Each time we get a new library file to link our test programs to test, we run a script to recompile and run our test bucket against.  The problem is that the compiling takes fairly long, especially if the environment is virtual.

Is there a way to compile the .h header files once, put in a separate object file and have those many .c source files link to said object file?  I think this will speed up compiling time.  I am willing to change/remove all the #include in the .c source programs.

**Any suggestions to speeding up compile time is greatly appreciated.**

Also, I should say that a script executes a makefile **PER** .c source test program!  The makefile is not told to compile all programs in the current directory.  Each test program is compiled into its own executable.

Comment: Header files are not compiled. They are #included into .c files which are then compiled. For the most part, header files just contain declarations which allow the .c files to reference functions, structs, datatypes, etc. without them being defined in that .c file.

Comment: @master_latch Unfortunately, the programmers that created the header files actually wrote thousands of lines of implementation code.  They did not use it for declaration purposes.  The code in the .h files is shared code used in all .c file test programs....So, it sounds like "precompiled headers" might be a solution.  Or maybe to create a dummy .c file which includes the .h header files and create an object out of that and then all .c files link to that?

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize pre-compiled headers was a thing -- but now that I think of it, I remember seeing it as an option in MSVS. Glad someone was able to answer your question!

Answer (score 2):

You could use precompiled header feature. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html

Comment: Read the first sentence in the hyperlink.  This seems to be exactly what I need!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just an update.  I have done what Yong Tiger has said.  The compilation time has changed from 982 seconds to 287 seconds.  A little over 3 times faster!

Answer (score 1):

You've asked further suggestions to speed up your compilation.

One way can be using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/). Basically, ccache keeps a cache of the object files compiled so far and returns them (instead of re-compiling again over and over) when it recognises that the same source file is being compiled again.

Using it should be as simple as

1. Install ccache
2. Prefix your gcc/cc/g++ command with ccache

Comment: Thanks for this!  Have you used this program before?  If the source code in the test programs are the same, and the library file we are linking to is different, will it need to recompile still?  Sometime we don't have any source code changes and need to test against a different library file.

Comment: Basically, it only re-compiles if there is any change in the code (either .c or .h). If you only link the same .o against a different .so, it does re-use the same .o it has in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your headers. Strip off all definition and leave in header. Strip off all implementation and put in new .c. Compile as library. Link with solution. Distribute library on runtime system.

Comment: I wish I could.  The creators of the regression bucket would not allow  this since the gain from the time spent does not justify it.  Your suggestion is definitely the right way of doing it though.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3080362 wow, the gain definitely justify the effort. It turns out the creators don't want you prove their way of doing is wrong... :) My suggestion, do it anyway. When you start reusing the code easily, they'll have to bury their head and be ashamed. Plus, regarding header, their should be no implementation as header is intended for content declaration only. Putting too much implementation there is abuse and laziness.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the way libraries typically work is by using precompiled code in object files ( .so on Linux systems? ), while providing header files ( .h ) for use in projects.

What happens is when you compile, the `#include <library.h>` directive finds that header and pastes its contents in the source file being compiled. Then, once the source file is compiled, it is linked to the precompiled object file. That way, the library can be included in a huge number of projects without it needing to be compiled from source each time. The only part that must be recompiled when linking to a library is the ( relatively ) small amount of code in the headers, which essentially makes library functions and variables accessible to the source code.

All this means is that to drastically speed up compilation, your best bet is to take all of the functions out of the 10 .h files, and instead leave only the function prototypes in the headers. Once you have all of the functions in separate .c source files, you can compile them into an object file ( typically `-c` flag ). Then, whenever you need to compile a new program against the 10 headers you typically use, you can instead include your stripped down version of the headers, and link to the precompiled object. Since only the new code in the .c file has to be compiled, instead of all of the code in the headers, the process should be much faster.